# How do I display an MFC control in a windows forms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, mfc, c++-cli

I'd like to create a windows forms control which shows an MFC control such as `CIPAddressCtrl`, with a working Text property and TextChanged event.  How do I display an MFC control in a windows forms application?  I'm happy to use C++/CLI if necessary.

NOTE: I'm not asking how to create a brand new windows forms control; I want to host a legacy control in a windows forms app.

Answer (score 5):

[This article](http://bartjolling.blogspot.com/2008/11/developing-windows-forms-control-using.html) presents a solution which will wrap your MFC control. The neat trick of this is its use of SubclassWindow in the override of Control::OnHandleCreated. The rest of the code involves manually wrapping the attributes of the MFC control with .NET properties.

Answer (score 1):

In my similar case, `SubclassWindow` in `OnHandleCreated` didn't work for some reason. After some struggle, I got it work (without C++/CLI):

First, get a HWND from [`Form#Handle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.iwin32window.handle(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass it to your MFC DLL.

```csharp
class GuestControl : Control
{
    private IntPtr CWnd { get; set; }

    public GuestControl()
    {
        CWnd = attach(Handle);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
       if (disposing)
       {
          detach(CWnd);
       }

       base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    [DllImport("your_mfc_dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr attach(IntPtr hwnd);
    [DllImport("your_mfc_dll")]
    private static extern void detach(IntPtr hwnd);
}
```

Then, in your DLL, [`CWnd::Attach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc368430.aspx) to the obtained HWND and initialize the control. Clean up with [`CWnd::Detach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc368495.aspx) on Dispose.

```c++
/** Attach to C# HWND and initialize */
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) CWnd* PASCAL attach(HWND hwnd) {
    auto w = std::make_unique<CWnd>();

    if (!w->Attach(hwnd)) { return nullptr; }

    // ... initialize your MFC control ...

    return w.release();
}

/** Detach and delete CWnd */
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void PASCAL detach(CWnd *cwnd) {
    auto w = std::unique_ptr<CWnd>(cwnd);
    w->Detach();
}
```

See [GuestControl.cs](https://github.com/snipsnipsnip/mfc-on-winforms-example/blob/master/CWndOnForm/Host/GuestControl.cs#L27) / [guest.cpp](https://github.com/snipsnipsnip/mfc-on-winforms-example/blob/master/CWndOnForm/guest/guest.cpp#L71)<sup>*</sup> for a full example.

**Edit:** The code in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46003104/188256) also use `Attach`/`Detach`.

<sup>* [The example](https://github.com/snipsnipsnip/mfc-on-winforms-example/) is my work. (MIT License)</sup>